# Policisto or Policano

Tags: word-formation

I've always used *policano* but today I discovered that *policisto*, while not as common, is in fairly wide use. It is even found in some reputable dictionaries. Is there a reason to prefer one term or the other?

It seems to me that if *polico* means "police force", a member of that force would necessarily be a *policano.* On the other hand, a *policisto* would have to be someone who is habitually or professionally involved with the verb *polici*. This verb is not found in dictionaries, and neither is it found in use anywhere in the Tekstaro.

Alternatively, a *policisto* could be someone professionally involved with *polico* - whatever that might mean exactly.

The best justification I have been able to find for the frequent use of *policisto* is national language influence (German: *Polizist*).

Is there an internal (to Esperanto) reason to support the derivation of *policisto* from *policano*? Have we reached the point where *policisto* is common enough and we just have to accept it even if there is no logical reason for it?

Comment: Is -ist really only used with verbs?

Comment: I stand corrected. (I don't know what I was thinking - since *dentisto* is a glaring counter-example.) I've modified my question slightly with this in mind. I was probably led astray by the thought that *isto* is often contrasted with *anto*. I also rolled back the recent edits to my question since some of them changed the meaning. My question is based on the though that *policisto* is indeed fairly common, just not **as** common as *policano.* The rolled-back edit said "not **that** common, which is completely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PIV, the suffix *-isto* is primarily defined as:

> *Persono, kiu profesie, daŭre, prefere aŭ ofte sin okupas pri la afero difinita de la **radiko***
>
> Person, who professionally, continually, preferentially, or frequently, is occupied with the subject defined by the **root**

The root-word does not have to be a verb or to possess a verbal form in routine use: consider *maristo* or *arbaristo* for example. (Note however that Esperanto permits extremely free verbification, and *polici, mari* and *arbari* are valid words. *Polici* is included in Wells's dictionary.) PIV mentions *policano* once but then defines *kaŝpolicisto* as plain-clothes policeman.

The word *policisto* appears in *Fundamenta Krestomatio, Marta,* and *Metropoliteno*. The word *policano* appears in the *Ekzercaro* and *La Revizoro*. Both appear in *La Faraono* and both are used very frequently in *Monato* articles.

If you need to refer to a person who studies police forces academically you could use *policologo*.

As for the difference between *-isto* and *-anto*, PIV says:

> *La suf.* ist *montras precize la profesiecon kontraste al* ant, *kiu signifas fojan, okazan faranton, k al* ul, *kiu montras iel personiĝon de la agado:* «trompanto» *fojfoje trompas,* «trompisto» *vivas el trompoj,* «trompulo» *estas homo esence karakterizebla per trompemo.*
>
> The suffix *-ist-* indicates precisely the professional nature in contrast to *-ant-*, which means doer from time to time or on a specific occasion, and to *-ul-*, which indicates a sort of personification of the action: a *trompanto* deceives people from time to time, a *trompisto* lives by deceiving people, a *trompulo* is a person essentially characterized by a tendency to deceive.

The verbification of the root-word *polico* follows the pattern of intended purpose: just as the intended purpose of a *broso* is to *brosi*, the intended purpose of a *polico* is to *polici*.

In nearly all contexts there should be no real difference between *policisto* and *policano*. Some people might consider use of *-isto* to be wrong for a volunteer or temporary member of the force, but that seems questionable to me.

Comment: Certainly there are many examples on non-verb *istoj* (*dentisto* springs to mind). What's missing from this answer from the point of view of what I was trying to ask are (1) what function of Esperanto word-formation allows us to go from *polico* to *polici* with the specific definition in Wells, and (2) is one of the terms (*policisto* *policano*) more logical or accurate than the other. In my investigation, I find a lot of people commenting that they're suddenly surprised by the existence of the other term.

Comment: I've edited. Briefly: (1) in this situation the root-word is an object created to perform an action, and so the verb is the action; (2) no, they are generally equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I still have my doubts about *polici* which is in Wells only on the English-to-Esperanto side. It's not the main part of my question though. Still, there's a difference between an action done with a tool (*brosi*) and one done by an *adminstracio*. Consider other words defined as administrations. *Doganisto doganas? Kanceliero kancelarias? Admiralitati?* Of course, the parallel between *doganisto* and *policisto* is clear enough. At this point, I'm convinced by your point 2 above. Thanks.